# Android: How to test Activity transition animation with Espresso?

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation, android-espresso

How can we automate the activity transition animation testing with Espresso or any other tool instead of viewing the screen ?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that testing animations is out of Espresso scope, since they recommend to turn off the animations: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup.html#set-up-environment

Comment: It may be, but do you know any other tool achieve it anyway ?